# Error when trying to add a controller to a Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to add a controller to an MVC .net framework Web API by right clicking on the Controllers folder and select add - new - controller.  I am selecting

> Web API 2 Controller with read/write actions

I then give it a name of `CurrentValueController` and click ok.

I then get the following error:

[image: Error message pop up box]

Not sure what is means by `value` as i dont have that as a parameter name.

Comment: restart VS instance?

Comment: restart the system

Comment: Done that and restarted my PC - same issue